# Drawing a polynomial

Tags: algorithm

I have a polynomial form:

> `w(x) = a +b(x-x1) + c(x-x1)^2*(x-x2) + d(x-x1)^2*(x-x2)^2+....`

Does anybody know a fast algorithm to counting this polynomial?

I want to draw this polynomial, but first i have to count the value, but I can't find any fast and interesting method to that.

Comment: By "counting" you probably mean "evaluating", right?

Comment: Yes, by counting i mean 'evaluating'

Comment: there is a polynomial-time algorithm..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is faster algorithm than iterating over the whole polynom. As it is not obvious from your description what exactly is the rule by which you form the terms I can not offer a solution but it is even better if you come up with it yourself.

From what I see the x-dependent part for each consecutive term is formed by multiplying what you have so  far by another monomial. If that is so, keep the value between iterations of the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Write a parser to get the individual elements of the expression such as `a`, `b`, `x`, `x1`, etc and `2`, `*`, `+`, `^`, `(`, `)`, etc.

Then use the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to transform the expression into [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Then evaluate it using a stack or a tree.

If you intend to evaluate the same expression many times, you may want to eliminate common subexpressions (e.g. `x - x1` repeats multiple times and you may calculate it just once). There are ways to do that as well. But before you go there, first see if what you get without such optimizations is really not sufficient.